# Do we want Hats?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Since Robotics.SE doesn't have any mods yet, I'm posting to you all directly.

### What are these hats you speak of?

Last year around Christmas time [arQAde](http://gaming.stackexchange.com) had an awesome promotion in which they awarded hats for gravatars for completing basic tasks around the site. If you don't remember it, here is a [link](http://stackexchange.com/promos/2/hat-dash) the promo from last year (and [another!](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/)).

[image: hats]

[image: hatrack]

This year, SE is planning to run it for *everyone* because we all love hats, right? *Right?!*

### Why are you making a meta post?

In order to get this awesome hat promotion, we have to ***opt in***. That means acting on this meta post: voting it up, answering in the affirmative, positive comments, and/or just directing positive energy this direction!

HOWEVER: this promotion is **optional** for sites, and/or individual users. If you all *do not* want this event to happen here, feel free to voice that opinion. Users who with to opt out will be provided with an "I hate Hats" link to remove the presence of hats from their view of the site.

I think this is a great opportunity for Robotics.SE to grow and get even more awesome content as we head towards gradumatation. Plus, it'll be a lot of fun!

### What if I want to know more?

Please let us know what you think -- this is *your* site and we want to do things that *you* feel support the community here!

I'm happy to answer any questions in comments/answers. I'll do my best to be as forthcoming as I can without giving away too much!

Comment: This was adapted from [this post elsewhere on the network](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1420/do-you-like-hats).

Comment: Yes (well I do at least). Actually, I was wondering why we didn't have this post, but then thought maybe beta sites weren't included. Good to know we can participate.

Comment: @ronalchn Nope, all sites (beta and graduated alike!) are eligible for this promo. :)

Comment: I whole-hatted-ly agree (see what I did there?)

Comment: @ThomasH - lol :-)

Answer (score 8):

This looks like a great idea, I'd certainly be happy to have Hats on *Robotics*.

Badges are great, but with plenty of people here on *Robotics* being new to Stack Exchange in general, having a fun way to promote the norms of Stack Exchange behaviour would be a great way to engage people in the site and encourage community building.

Comment: Yup! Hats are *badges you can wear!* which is extra awesomesauce. :D